# How can I embed SSRS reports in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, reporting-services, embedded

Any suggestions on same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not use SSRS in integrated mode, even in on-prem SharePoint 2013.

When we need make reports available in SharePoint, we use one of three methods:

- Page Viewer web part and use SSRS “URL Access” (or CEWP and iframe tag) - embeds the SSRS Viewer
- simple link to the URL of the report, opening in its own tab/window
- wrote a poweshell “report scheduler” that runs reports via SSRS api and writes them to a PDF and then uploads to a document library. Kind of like data driven subscriptions in SSRS. Works when there are not lots of parameters and timely data is not required.

Just some options.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Integrated Mode is not supported in the office 365. Check this [Feature availability across Office 365 plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx#bkmk_tableo365)

as a workaround, we can export ssrs report to excel and then import the excel files to sharepoint list, then you can display this excel file in an excel web access web part.  read this post for more information: [How can I show SSRS reports in SharePoint online , SharePoint O365 ?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-show-ssrs-reports-in-sharepoint-online/1d94a167-6ac7-49f3-9201-c6d04df4ff9a?auth=1)